# Imagem some ao rodar o projeto

Tags: c#, wpf

Boa tade pessoal, estou com problemas ao usar uma imagem utilizando o WPF, eu estou tentando utilizar o Uri para poder instanciar a imagem e executar o projeto, porém da um Erro de IsFrozen is false e não executa o projeto, ao usar e eu tentei usar o modo normal abaixo

```
<Window x:Class="curso.MainWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:curso"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes" 
        mc:Ignorable="d"
         TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
            TextElement.FontWeight="Regular"
         TextElement.FontSize="13"
         TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"
         TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"
         Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
         FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}" Height="600" Width="1024" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None">


    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="AbrirMenu">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridMenu">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="200"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="70"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="FecharMenu">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridMenu">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="70"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="200"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="ButtonAbrir">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource AbrirMenu}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="ButtonFecharMenu">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FecharMenu}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>



    <Grid>

        <Grid Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF9D6ED7">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0">


                <Button x:Name="ButtonMinimizar" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniAccentButton}" Width="25" Height="26"  Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="ButtonMinimizar_Click">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Minus" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.812,0.44"/>
                </Button>

                <Button x:Name="ButtonMaximizar" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniAccentButton}" Width="25" Height="26"  Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Click="ButtonMaximizar_Click">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ArrowExpand" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.812,0.44"/>
                </Button>

                <Button x:Name="ButtonFechar" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniAccentButton}" Width="25" Height="26"  Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="ButtonFechar_Click">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Power" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.812,0.44" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="GridMenu" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFD8C8C8" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA09D9D" Offset="0"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" Color="#FFA09898" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="1"/>
            </Grid.Effect>
            <Grid Background="#FFa46fe4">

                <Button x:Name="ButtonAbrir"  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniAccentButton}" Width="25" Height="26"  Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Visibility="Collapsed" Click="ButtonAbrir_Click">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ArrowLeft" RenderTransformOrigin="0.396,0.544" />
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="ButtonFecharMenu"  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniAccentButton}" Width="25" Height="26"  Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Click="ButtonFecharMenu_Click">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Menu" RenderTransformOrigin="0.396,0.544" />
                </Button>
                <Viewbox>
                    <Image Source="assets/logo.png"></Image>
                </Viewbox>
            </Grid>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                <Button x:Name="ButtonInicio" Margin="10" Background="#FF7E2AE2" BorderBrush="#FF7E2AE2" Click="ButtonInicio_Click" >
                    <Grid Width="150">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ViewDashboard" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Inicio"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Button>

                <Button  x:Name="ButtonQuarto1" Margin="10" Background="#FF7E2AE2" BorderBrush="#FF7E2AE2" Click="ButtonQuarto1_Click">
                    <Grid Width="150">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="bed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Quarto 1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Button>

                <Button x:Name="ButtonQuarto2" Margin="10" Background="#FF7E2AE2" BorderBrush="#FF7E2AE2" Click="ButtonQuarto2_Click">
                    <Grid Width="150">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="bed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Quarto 2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Button>

                <Button x:Name="ButtonQuarto3" Margin="10" Background="#FF7E2AE2" BorderBrush="#FF7E2AE2" Click="ButtonQuarto3_Click">
                    <Grid Width="150">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="bed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Quarto 3"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Button>

                <Button x:Name="ButtonCozinha" Margin="10" Background="#FF7E2AE2" BorderBrush="#FF7E2AE2" Click="ButtonCozinha_Click">
                    <Grid Width="150">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Kitchen" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Cozinha "/>
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="15*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="277*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="35*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="117*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="360*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image  Source="assets/logo.png" Grid.Column="2" Margin="31,93,264,92" Grid.Row="1">
            </Image>

            <Label Content="Bem vindo!" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#DDE23939" FontSize="40" FontFamily="Impact" Margin="149,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1"/>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

porém imagem aparece no design, porém ao executar o projeto a imagem simplesmente some... alguem conhece alguma solução?

Esses são meus diretórios:

[image: Diretórios]

Comment: Heitor! Poderia por favor anexar na pergunta algumas imagens dos seus diretórios do projeto e código onde esta este erro? agradeço desde já.

Comment: Envie também a mensagem de erro da saída.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bKV509yv este é o pastebin com o código, https://imgur.com/GUznEYL a print com os diretórios e o erro usando o bitmap image é: O valor especificado do tipo 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' deve ter IsFrozen definido como falso para modificação.

Comment: Coloque a imagem do diretório na pergunta e código não deve ser como imagem.

Comment: Já tentou definir diretamente `IsFrozen="false"` dentro de `<Image>`.

Comment: tente usar padrões como este: <Image x:Name="img1" Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="Both" Grid.Column="2" Margin="192,98,235.922,223.403" Grid.Row="1" Source="assets/logo.png"/>

Comment: Evite usar o ViewBox, fique atento a ancoragem vertical e horizontal e o strech da sua imagem.